# What does "my ($self, %myInputs) = @_;" mean?

Tags: perl, perl-module

I came across this line a lot of times in perl modules but I could not figure out what this exactly means.

```
my ($self, %myInputs) = @_;
```

Kindly explain me the statement so that I can proceed.

Answer (score 8):

Im guessing that is one of the first lines in a **class method function**. That line parses `@_` which is the [**list of the function arguements**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4563516/1520364), and **extracts the first param** which is always a **reference to the object** into `$self` and extracts the rest of them into a **hash** `%myInputs`. This ofcourse assumes that the function is called with the arguements in hash format, like in the below Perl/Tk function

```
$mw->Button(-text => "RIGHT", -command => sub { exit })
  ->pack(-side => 'right', -fill => 'both');
```

Answer (score 6):

> my ($self, %myInputs) = @_;

Not all functions receive the first argument `$self`. In fact, by convention, only the ones invoked using the arrow operator do `->`; invoking with `->` implicitly sends a special argument referring to the object. All functions and methods in perl are declared the same way (using keyword `sub`). Only invocation determines whether or not the function is a method.

The `my ($foo, $bar) = ( $x, $y );` is called parallel assignment. That's all that is going on here!

Observe a hash can be initialized from an array in Perl.

```
my @foo = qw/ foo bar baz quz /;
my %hash = @foo;
print $hash{foo}; # outputs bar
```

Because you're assigning to the hash `%myInputs`, the hash is explicitly assigned *all inputs that are not the implicitly sent* (because you're pulling that one off into `$self`). But be careful, it wouldn't make much sense to do the following right?

```
my @foo = qw/ foo bar baz /;
my %hash = @foo;
print $hash{baz} # what is this set too??
```

For the same reason, it also doesn't make much sense to invoke your function with an un-even amount of arguments! Both will generate a warning.

Comment: But what is the need of using $self! It just confuses me so much!

Comment: @user1855888 `$self` refers to the object you're calling on. If you call `my $a Animal->new`, and then you call `$a->run` then `$self` (first argument) inside of `sub run {}` would be set to `$a`. In other languages you call it `this`. You can call it `$this` in Perl too if you're used to that, `my $this = shift` (though it's against convention).

Answer (score 1):

In Perl `@_;` is a Global Array Special Variables

Similar as `@ARGV` The array contain the command-line arguments intended for the script.

So in `my ($self, %myInputs) = @_;`

`@_` would represent the argument of the Variable `$` in the Hash-Variables `%`