# Hash notation in `%oneobs= %{$obs[1]};`

Tags: perl

In the documentation for `Statistics::Regression`, the instructions to add an observation is:
   $reg->include( 2.0, [ 1.0, 3.0, -1.0 ] );

Then, to just run the regression on your own data:

```
my @obs;
observations are like: %oneobs= %{$obs[1]};
...
foreach my $obshashptr (@obs) { $reg->include( $_[1], $_[3] ); }
```

I'm confused by `%oneobs= %{$obs[1]}`: what does this notation mean? Further, what is `foreach my $obshashptr (@obs) { $reg->include( $_[1], $_[3] ); }` doing? Could someone help by showing me what these two statement are doing in more than one line?

It seems that `$_[1]` is the observation and `$_[3]` contains the predictor variables. So, `$_[3]` is an array..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`%{ }` is a hash dereference; what's inside it is a reference to a hash, and the contents of that hash are being assigned to `%oneobs`.

See http://perlmonks.org/?node=References+quick+reference

Comment: so `@obs` is an array of hash of arrays? Is my example structure correct: `my %hash1 = (1.0=>[1.0,2.0,1.0]);my %hash2 = (1.0=>[1.0,1.0,1.0]);my @obs = (\%hash1,\%hash2);`?

Comment: that would be an array of hashes of arrays, yes

Answer (score 1):

`my @obs;` is an array which contains hash reference at each index.

```
run_regression("bivariate regression",  $obshashptr->{someY}, [ "const", "someX" ] );
```

This calls the `run_regression` subroutine and passes 3 arguments.

Now check the subroutine.

```
sub run_regression {
  my $reg = Statistics::Regression->new( $_[0], $_[2] );
  foreach my $obshashptr (@obs) { $reg->include( $_[1], $_[3] ); }
  $reg->print();
}
```

The subroutine takes the arguments in `@_` array (see [What is the meaning of @_ in Perl?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4563485/what-is-the-meaning-of-in-perl)). Then you create `$reg` object of `Statistics::Regression` and you pass 2 arguments to `new` method. `$_[0]` means the first element of `@_` array which in this case is `bivariate regression`. `$_[2]` means the third argument.

Then `foreach` line loops through the array and assigns value at array's index to `$obshashptr` and then for each iteration of array you are calling the `include` method of `Statistics::Regression` and you are passing 2 arguments to it. First one is the value at second index of `@_` and second argument is value at 4th index of `@_`.

[image: http://i.imgur.com/cCMv1OT.png]

Comment: what is the value at the 4th index of @_? It seems that it's meant to be the array of predictor variables, but isn't it referring to the 4th argument given to `run_regression`? Otherwise `@_` changes inside the `foreach`, in which case it's referring to what?