# Array Syntax in Perl

Tags: php, arrays, perl, syntax

I have a question. I have to program a part in php but only got this Perl example and don't understand the exact Syntax:

```
#showGetInfo(
#   ['Customers/1001/Orders/1001'], #orders paths
#   ['Comment'],                    #additional order attributes
#   ['Street2'],                    #additional address attributes
#   ['TransID','Weight']            #additional lineitem attributes
#);
```

on another part in the file it says:

```
sub showGetInfo {
    my @Params = @_;
    my $ahResults = $OrderService->getInfo(@Params)->result;

    [...]
}
```

Except it is just a comment because of the #'s, I need to copy the structure to php.

I suppose there are arrays created, maybe even some arrays in another array but I don't understand especially how the arraystructure is built here. Can you help me and tell me what the variable @Params would look like in php?

Comment: take a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4563485/what-is-the-meaning-of-in-perl

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Can you help me and tell me what the variable @Params would look like in php?

In php `$Params` would be like in perl, array of array

```
array(
  array('Customers/1001/Orders/1001'), #orders paths
  array('Comment'),                    #additional order attributes
  array('Street2'),                    #additional address attributes
  array('TransID','Weight')            #additional lineitem attributes
);
```

Answer (score 4):

The sub `showGetInfo` gets a *list* of values passed as its arguments. Those end up in the array `@_`. That gets assigned to the new [lexical](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlsub.html#Private-Variables-via-my()) array `@Params`. Lexical means, it's only available in this `sub`.

Next, the method `getInfo()` is called on the object `$OrderService`. It is passed the same arguments that `shoGetInfo` got.

From the call you showed, let's look at those parameters:

> ```
> ['Customers/1001/Orders/1001'], #orders paths
> ```

This is an [array reference](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlreftut.html). It contains one value: The string `'Customers/1001/Orders/1001'`.

> ```
> ['Comment'],                    #additional order attributes
> ```

Again, an array ref with one string in it.

> ```
> ['Street2'],                    #additional address attributes
> ```

Another of those.

> ```
> ['TransID','Weight']            #additional lineitem attributes
> ```

This array reference contains two entries. One is the string `'TransID'`, the other `'Weight'`.

---

To translate this to PHP, you can just use normal arrays. No need for references like in Perl in PHP.